# Timer is not working truely

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer

Timer is working only one time. This service must be work in every 2minutes...
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        RuleContext entity = new RuleContext();
        private int id;
        private Timer _timer;
        private DateTime _lastRun = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

```
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        OnTimer();
    }

    public void OnTimer()
    {
        Timeout.Infinite);
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 2 * 60 * 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Start();

    }



    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        // ignore the time, just compare the date
        if (_lastRun.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date)
        {


            GetRule();




        }
    }



    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    public void GetRule()
    {



        var query = from ruleset in entity.RuleSets
                    join rule in entity.Rules on ruleset.Id equals rule.RuleSetId
                    join schedulerule in entity.Schedules on rule.ScheduleId equals schedulerule.Id

                    select new
                    {
                        Id = ruleset.Id,
                        daily = schedulerule.Daily,
                        mountly = schedulerule.Monthly,
                        dayofMounth = schedulerule.DayOfMonth,
                    };


        foreach (var q in query.ToList())
        {

            if (q.mountly && q.daily)
            {
                if (q.dayofMounth == (int)DateTime.Now.Day)
                {
                    UpdateValue(q.Id);
                }
            }

            else if (q.daily)
            {
                UpdateValue(q.Id);
            }

            else if (q.mountly)
            {
                if (q.dayofMounth == (int)DateTime.Now.Day)
                {
                    UpdateValue(q.Id);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void UpdateValue(int id)
    {
        var ruleSet = entity.RuleSets.First(k => k.Id == id);
        ruleSet.RcvByte = 0;
        ruleSet.SentByte = 0;
        entity.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to stop the timer...

Answer (score 0):

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

```
    // ignore the time, just compare the date
    if (_lastRun.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        GetRule();

   }
}
```

Since the AutoReset property is set to true, no need to Stop and Start timer.

Comment: I tried it, but timer works only one time again. Nothing is changed.

Comment: yes. I want to show u whole code. Maybe this fault come from foreach loop. I don't know.

Comment: Seems there is no problem with your timer code. Use try catch and check any exception occurred in GetRule() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
_timer.Stop();
```

this line is causing this problem. Remove it